# finding and copying files using shell script (folder name and file name is same)

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a directory that include several folders. I want to write a shell script to find a file in another directory that has the same name as the mentioned folders. 
To clarify I have a directory that include test1 and test2 folders. I have another directory that have two files with the names of test1 and test2. My goal is to go to the directory that have folders and then get the folder names. Then by using folder name find the file that has the same name and copy it to that folder that has the same name. 
I wrote the following script but it could not copy the file.

```
for d in /home/Documents/test/*/ ; do 
    find /home/Documents/binaries/ -name "$d" -type f -exec cp {} /home/Documents/test/$d \;
    cd "$d" 
done
```

Comment: are you getting an error ?

Comment: no. I only get this warning: find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  That means that '-name `/home/Documents/test/4e944142233cdded1e7307270db50d758dca7831.exe/'' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.  You might find the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-samefile'.  Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ `/home/Documents/test/4e944142233cdded1e7307270db50d758dca7831.exe/''.

Comment: I also test -wholename but got the same error

Answer (score 0):

`$d` will be set to a full path name, such as `/home/Documents/test/test1/`, but you only need `test1` as the argument for the `-name` primary. You can use parameter expansion to strip the leading path from the value of `$d`, but it will take two steps.

```
for d in /home/Documents/test/*/ ; do 
    fname=${d##*/}  # Strip /home/Documents/test/
    fname=${fname%/}    # Strip the trailing /
    # Note that d is already the full directory name you want to use
    # as the target file for `cp`
    find /home/Documents/binaries/ -name "$fname" -type f -exec cp {} "$d" \;
done
```

The `cd` command doesn't seem to accomplish anything useful, since you are using absolute path names throughout.

Simpler, though, would be to change the working directory to `/home/Documents/test` first.

```
cd /home/Documents/test/
for d in */; do
    find /home/Documents/binaries/ -name "$d" -type f -exec cp {} /home/Documents/test/"$d" \;
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I exactly use your script but still it does not copy anything! do you know why?

Comment: Change `... cp {} ..` into `... echo cp {} ..` and see what it says.

Comment: In the second solution you should strip the / as well. `d=${d%/}`